# Deactivated Visual Composer plugin, site crashed, what to do?

Tags: plugins

So I have deactivated the Visual Composer plugin from the WP admin panel and now the whole site is down and I'm getting this error:

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function vc_map() in xxxxxxx/**httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/df-shortcodes/vc-mod/vc_mod-extend.php** on line **135**

And this line does not even correspond to the Visual Composer plugin, how can I fix this?

I have access to the FTP.

Answer (score 1):

@dev_blast firstly deactivate the **DF_Shortcodes** plugin. Might be this will generating the issue.

Comment: is there a way to do this without accessing the admin dashboard?